# Insert predefined image if isn't selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image

I want to check if file is empty and insert a default image if it is empty to database, retrieving the image in another page

It is what I have, I don't know if I am doing right or not:

```
if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
 $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["inpFile"]["tmp_name"]));
 $username = trim($_REQUEST["username"]);
//Check if image is empty
 if(empty($file)){
   if($type == 1 || $type == 2 || $type == 3 || $type == 4){
     //Set $file a predefined image 
   }
 }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO pratos (name, image) VALUES ('$username', '$file')";
 $pdo->exec($sql);

}
```

I tried to give a file value if it is empty

```
$file = "../img/prato_default.png";
```

I want to send the path to database and retrieve it, showing the image. Here I have the code to select and show:

```
$pesquisa = "SELECT * FROM pratos WHERE categoria = '$categoria' AND sessao = '$sessao' AND tipo = '$tipo'";
$resultado_pesquisa = mysqli_query($conn, $pesquisa);

<?php while ($rows_pesquisas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_pesquisa)) { ?>
<img <?php echo 'src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($rows_pesquisas['imagem']) . '"'; ?> class="image">
```

Comment: Check in your php if the user has set an image, and use your default image if not.

Comment: I already did that but my problem is to **insert** the image into a variable and send it to **Mysql**.
I don't know neither how to **retrieve** the image via **URL**

Comment: There are quite a lot of tutorials and examples for that. For example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Please do some research first, make an attempt to solve this problem yourself (= do coding), and if you get stuck then you can show us your code and have a good basis to ask a question here.

Comment: This should be done on the backend - if the `image` is missing, just take the default one and save that into the database.